# Eclipse: Link to file in workspace and open in internal editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm porting C++ code to Java and I have to constantly refer from the Java source to the C++ source. I would like to be able to hyperlink directly there. For example, in Java source:

```
/**
 * This is a port of C++ from <a href="../../another/project/src/Source.cpp">here</a>.
 */
```

This hyperlink works but it opens in an external web browser. I would like it to open in the internal Eclipse text editor, or anything but a browser! I know it doesn't make much sense to open a C++ file inside Eclipse but I just want to view the source with some basic functionality like navigation and search. Opening it in a web browser with odd formatting and lacking basic tools is not very helpful with thousands of lines of C++ code! Notice that this is not a link to Java source in the same project or a dependent project, so `{@link SomeClass}` is inappropriate as it would never be understood by the JavaDoc compiler.

I'm looking for any solution that will let me cmd/ctrl-click the link and have it open in some kind of text editor. Preferably it would be the internal Eclipse text editor but anything will do:

- Is there an Eclipse plugin that already does something like this?
- Is there a trick to make the JavaDoc anchor launch anything but a web browser?
- Can I override the URL handling in OSX to open *certain* URLs with Eclipse?
- It could be a non-JavaDoc comment but as Eclipse renders hyperlinks in JavaDoc rollovers it seems like the place to start

The URL itself is not an issue. I happen to have checked out the C++ project from Git into my Eclipse workspace, so I'm using a relative URL here. If I have to use absolute filesystem paths that's fine too.

Solving this would save me hours of tedium!